# Footer wont stick to bottom

Tags: html, css

Ive been playing around with my html/css for so long and i cant seem to get it to stick to the bottom below all the content. Right now, it starts on the bottom of the window, which overlaps content. It should be below all the content. Any help? Heres the site.. (the footer is last thing before  wrapped in a div with class="footer") http://alenlocksmith.com/

Comment: can we see the code?  Have you tried using a fixed position div?

Comment: Do you want it always just under the content, or under the content if the window height is too small, and at the botom of the screen otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want it just under the content, remove `position:absolute` in `#footer`

Answer (score 2):

try using `position:fixed;` this should fix your error

Comment: `position:fixed;` will make it always stick at the bottom of your screen, so it will overlap the content if your window height is too small

Answer (score 1):

Visit http://www.cssstickyfooter.com - It works like a charm every time!